On proving a homogenous symmetric inequality that resembles Schur's

Given $a,b,c \geq 0$ then show that:
$$\sum_{\mathrm{sym}} ( a^5 + a^2 b^2 c - a^4b - a^2 b^3 ) \geq 0.$$

I think it may be somehow connected to fifth-degree Schur's inequality, but the usual form of Schur's is cyclic sums whereas this is a symmetric one. I really have no idea how to prove it, it seems beyond my current limited knowledge. Also note that the equality occurs iff $a=b=c>0$ or $a=0, b=c>0$ and its permutations, that's why I have thought of Schur's ineq. Any small hints/advice would be invaluable to me. Hope you have a great day!

To confirm, do you want a symmetric sum or a cyclic sum?

@Fuzzy - Just FYI - the standard Schur inequality of any degree is symmetric.  It can be represented as a cyclic sum, but if you expand you will notice its always symmetric.

We can convert into cyclic form:
$$
\sum\limits_{sym} ( a^5 + a^2 b^2 c - a^4b - a^2 b^3 ) = \sum\limits_{cyc} ( 2a^5 + 2a^2 b^2 c - a^4b - a^4c - a^3 (b^2 + c^2) )
$$
Splitting off the 5th degree Schur inequality  $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^5-a^4b-a^4c+a^3bc)\geq0$ leaves to show
$$
 \sum\limits_{cyc} ( a^5 + 2a^2 b^2 c  - a^3 (b^2 + c^2 + bc) ) \ge 0
$$
This can be written as
$$
 \sum\limits_{cyc} ( a^5 + a^2 b^2 c  + a^2c^2b - a^3 (b^2 + c^2 + bc) ) 
= (a + b + c) \sum\limits_{cyc}  a^2 (a - b) (a - c) 
$$
but $
\sum\limits_{cyc}  a^2 (a - b) (a - c) \ge 0 
$ is again true by Schur, so we are done.$ \qquad \square$

Very nice solution, thanks for your keen observation! I wonder how we can come up with the magical factor like that. Can I ask if there's a factorization method in general sir?

Well, the "magical factor" cannot be obtained in some "mechanical" form which is guaranteed to  result in such a factor. However, a general advice is to make use of symmetry or cyclicity - in this case $\sum\limits_{cyc} a^2 b^2 c   = \sum\limits_{cyc} a^2c^2b$. This allows for the arguments of the $\sum\limits_{cyc}$ to have more flexibility, in order to be able to split off relevant factors.


Generalized Schur's inequality states that if $(x, y, z)$ and $(a, b, c)$ are positive and similarly ordered, then
$$ x(a-b)(b-c) + y(b-c)(b-a) + z(c-a)(c-b) \geq 0$$
Main idea: To apply this, we spread out the symmetric terms into a cyclic form, so that we have a factor of $(a-b)(a-c)$ (See Note 1). This gives us the corresponding $x$, which we then verify that $(a-b)(x-y) \geq 0$ so they are similarly ordered.

Observe that if we spread out the terms as
$$ 2a^5 - a^4b - a^4c - a^3b^2 - a^3c^2 + a^2b^2c + a^2bc^2 \\
= a^2(2a+b+c)(a-b)(a-c), \\$$
hence we can rewrite the LHS in cyclic Schur's form of
$$ \sum_{sym} a^5 +a^2b^2c - a^4b - a^2b^3 = \sum_{cyc} a^2(2a+b+c)(a-b)(a-c) $$
This leads to $x = a^2(2a+b+c), y = b^2(a+2b+c), z = c^2(a+b+2c) $.
Finally, verify that $ x-y = (a-b)(2a^2+3ab+2b^2+ac+bc)$, so they are similarly ordered.
Hence by Generalized Schur's, the inequality is true.
Note

Recall that by Remainder Factor Theorem, $a-b$ is a factor of the expression, if when we substitute $a=b$, it evaluates to 0. This makes it easier to see how to fit the terms together.
This is essentially what Andreas did, just that I combined his 2 parts ($\sum a^3 (a-b)(a-c) \geq 0$, $ \sum a^2(a+b+c)(a-b)(a-c) \geq 0$). It's a bit more natural than guessing the "magical factor".


Alternative proof.
WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c$.
We have
\begin{align*}
 &\sum_{\mathrm{sym}} (a^5 + a^2 b^2 c - a^4b - a^2 b^3)\\
 ={}& \sum_{\mathrm{sym}} a^4(a-b) - \sum_{\mathrm{sym}} a^2b^2(b-c)\\
 ={}& \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a^4(a-b) + \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} b^4(b-a) - \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a^2b^2(b-c)
 - \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} b^2a^2(a-c)\\
 ={}& \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a^4(a-b) + \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} b^4(b-a) - \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} c^2a^2(a-b)
 - \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} c^2b^2(b-a)\\
 ={}& \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a^4 - b^4 - c^2a^2 + b^2c^2)(a - b)\\
 ={}& \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a^2 + b^2 - c^2)(a + b)(a - b)^2\\
 ={}& (a^2 + b^2 - c^2)(a + b)(a - b)^2
 + (b^2 + c^2 - a^2)(b + c)(b - c)^2\\
 &\qquad  + (c^2 + a^2 - b^2)(c + a)(c - a)^2\\
 \ge{}& 
 (b^2 + c^2 - a^2)(b + c)(b - c)^2 
  + (c^2 + a^2 - b^2)(c + b)(b - c)^2\\
 ={}& 2c^2(b + c)(b - c)^2\\
 \ge{}& 0.
\end{align*}
